# How to send HTML-formatted message with standard mail function in PHP

Tags: php, webmail

I am trying to use the following in my contact us form to receive nicely formatted html email from my visitors:

```
$message .='<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="margin-bottom: 20px">';
$message .='<caption style="text-align:left;background:#eee;padding:5px;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;">Webmail</caption>';
$message .='<tr><td width="200"><strong>Date</strong></td><td width="600" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">'.$todayis.'</td></tr>';
$message .='<tr><td width="200"><strong>From</strong></td><td width="600" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">'.$name.'</td></tr>';
$message .='<tr><td width="200"><strong>Email</strong></td><td width="600" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">'.$email.'</td></tr>';
$message .='<tr><td width="200"><strong>Subject</strong></td><td width="600" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">'.$recipient.'</td></tr>';
$message .='</table>';
$message .= '<div style="width:770px;background:#eee;padding:15px;">';
$message .= '<div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;padding-bottom: 10px;">Your Message</div>';
$message .= $message;
$message .= '</div>';
$message .='<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="margin-bottom: 20px">';
$message .='<caption style="text-align:left;background:#eee;padding:5px;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;">Webmail Data</caption>';
$message .='<tr><td width="200"><strong>IP Address</strong></td><td width="600" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">'.$ip.'</td></tr>';
$message .='<tr><td width="200"><strong>Browser Info</strong></td><td width="600" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">'.$httpagent.'</td></tr>';
$message .='<tr><td width="200"><strong>Referral</strong></td><td width="600" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">'.$httpref.'</td></tr>';
$message .='</table>';

$headers = "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The problem I have is that when I use `text/html` the email shows as sent but I am not getting it, when I am changing it to `text/plain` everything works fine except that I get everything in plain text without any HTML formatting.

I am on my own dedicated Apache server, running Plesk 12.0.18 and CentOS6.6 do I need to configure anything on the server? I have tried to configure the email to receive everything in HTML format, but seems like it did not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe it is received in spam folder?

Comment: I have checked this too, but nothing is there either

Comment: Actually you were right, I have turned the spam filter off and this email got through, but again in plain text format. What should I do? I do not want to turn my SPAM filter off.

Comment: Answering with a “use this library” to a plain-function question is not best style, but in this case (email via PHP) [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) has proven to be worth consideration. It handles many edge cases, that people inexperienced in the intricacies of mail sending simply don't know.

Comment: @Boldewyn, I have cheeked this library, but there are no solutions for overcoming your own SPAM filter that I could refer to. There is apparent problem with SPAM, which is not letting the email in HTML format and then the second problem is HTML it self, which is not being displayed in Outlook when received.

Comment: @AlexB PHPMailer handles correct formation of mail headers dependent on what SMTP service you are running and alot of other cases that might get your email to not be send or recieved as desired. Also it can be important to set up the correct DNS settings. Are you running your own server or are you using some shared hosting provider?

Comment: @EJTH I am running my own dedicated server with my own SMTP protocols

Comment: What do you mean by 'Your own smtp protocols' did you write the SMTP server yourself ? Do you use sendmail or postfix?

Comment: What I meant was my SMTP is mail.mydomain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Php Html email**

```
<?php
$to = "abc@gmail.com";
$subject = "PUT_SUBJECT_HERE";
$mail_body = '<html>
<body bgcolor="#573A28" topmargin="25">
Put HTML content here with variables from PHP if you like
Variable display Example: ' . $subject . ' 
<h1>this is a heading</h1>
</body>
</html>';
//$headers  = "From: abc@gmail.com";
//$headers .= "Content-type: text/html";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <abc@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);
?>
```

Enjoy this code